# Valor minimo de um linha excluindo os valores zero (R)

Tags: r, data.frame

```
    TIMP3 TOTS3      UGPA3     USIM5     VALE3     VALE5    VIVT4 VLID3     WEGE3

1 0.7941716     0 0.00915221 0.2751215 0.3803796 0.5162442 1.505921     0 0.5559166

2 0.7710909     0 0.09351134 0.3925726 0.3687917 0.5158750 1.469548     0 0.5389812

3 0.7634292     0 0.10535813 0.4906756 0.3575568 0.5170484 1.433848     0 0.5225616

4 0.7479777     0 0.26867319 0.5142030 0.3754794 0.5018268 1.407619     0 0.5066423

5 0.7520354     0 0.29342233 0.6426008 0.4840935 0.6466121 1.400813     0 0.4912079

6 0.7559319     0 0.28448351 0.6571724 0.4694412 0.6365194 1.360621     0 0.4762438
```

Estou usando :

```
MIN = apply(EWMA_SD252[,2:102]*100,1,min)
```

Mas gostaria de pegar o minimo de cada linha porem desconsiderando os valores 0, alguma ideia ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o `min` no `apply`, você pode aplicar uma função anônima que selecione o mínimo somente dos números diferentes de zero (`function(x) min(x[x!=0])`). Por exemplo, no seu código ficaria assim:

```
MIN = apply(EWMA_SD252[,2:102]*100,1,function(x) min(x[x!=0]))
```

Comment: Show, muito obrigado ! Funcionou